# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Writers Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Oh drat.  I wish this hadn't happened during Thanksgiving week; I only got partway through it. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is there enough money in writing for me to quit my dead end job?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9064/is-there-enough-money-in-writing-for-me-to-quit-my-dead-end-job)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is it possible to write a novel completely devoid of dialogue?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/is-it-possible-to-write-a-novel-completely-devoid-of-dialogue)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are collection of short stories more likely to sell than single short stories?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9095/are-collection-of-short-stories-more-likely-to-sell-than-single-short-stories)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Assessing what writing skills are missing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9154/assessing-what-writing-skills-are-missing)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I avoid word repetition in the following paragraph?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9147/how-can-i-avoid-word-repetition-in-the-following-paragraph)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When is it acceptable to refer to an undefined group of people in academic writing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9120/when-is-it-acceptable-to-refer-to-an-undefined-group-of-people-in-academic-writi)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are good guidelines to follow when writing app reviews?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/what-are-good-guidelines-to-follow-when-writing-app-reviews)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Software to organise world building?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9035/software-to-organise-world-building)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Should subsection headings sometimes repeat section headings?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9077/should-subsection-headings-sometimes-repeat-section-headings)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [For Sci-Fi books, what is the purchasing split between regular and ebooks?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9101/for-sci-fi-books-what-is-the-purchasing-split-between-regular-and-ebooks)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---